# How can I convert a list of dictionaries into a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I convert a list of dictionaries into a nested dictionary, where the values are the dictionaries from the list and the keys are the number of each dictionary's place in the list?

I'm working in Python, and currently I have a list of about a thousand dictionaries (982, to be precise). I'm trying (and failing, at the moment) to use this list of dictionaries to populate the values while populating the keys with each respective dictionary's location in the original list (0 being first, 1 being second, and so on). I'm having trouble accomplishing this, however.

In my initial attempt to do this, I simply used dict.fromkeys, like so:

```
newdict = dict.fromkeys(range(982)), dict_list)
```

This command never completed, however, so I assumed there was a problem with it and began looking for another solution.

What I've attempted since then is writing a for loop that cycles through the list, and using dict.fromkeys in order to create my new dictionary. For example,

```
for x in dict_list:
    newdict = dict.fromkeys(range(982), x)
```

This code populates my dictionary's keys as intended (from 0-981), but inserts the same dictionary (from the list of dictionaries) for all of the new dictionary's values. The dictionary in question is the last one listed in the original list of dictionaries.
Here's an example of what the output looks like, for clarity's sake:

```
{0 : {'Male': 506, 'Female': 476}
{1 : {'Male': 506, 'Female': 476}
{2 : {'Male': 506, 'Female': 476}
```

...and so on.

Can anybody help me determine what's wrong with my second attempt to accomplish this? What am I missing?

Comment: Why use a dictionary, instead of a list, since the keys are the integer index?

Comment: The problem with `dict.fromkeys(keys, value)` is that you use an iterable for keys thats ok, but the value is the same for all the keys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to loop over the list. Since we have an iterable which is your list of dictionaries we can simply use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in to convert it to a nested dictionary.

```
x = [{'Male': 506, 'Female': 476}, {'Male': 507, 'Female': 477}]

dict(enumerate(x))
{0: {'Female': 476, 'Male': 506}, 1: {'Female': 477, 'Male': 507}}
```

As for why *your* attempt is incorrect.

You are looping over your list of dictionaries and setting `newdict` equal to the value of your expression. You don't use this variable nor save it anywhere so you only access it once the loop is done which is why it is filled with only the last item in your list of dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Looks like I need to review dictionaries and their related operations...

Comment: @datanovice you should also think if what you're asking for is necessary. Having a dict with indexes as keys is basically a list with a memory over-head...